# When a variable is closed twice, where is it stored?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures

I was reading with interesting this article called [C# Closures Explained](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained), which states:

> You see, the C# compiler detects when a delegate forms a closure which is passed out of the current scope and it promotes the delegate, and the associated local variables into a compiler generated class. This way, it simply needs a bit of compiler trickery to pass around an instance of the compiler generated class, so each time we invoke the delegate we are actually calling the method on this class.

So essentially a closed variable is stored as a member variable of an anonymous class that also contains the delegate representing the lambda expression or other code that is closing over the variable.

If that is the case, what happens when a method contains two different lambda expressions and both of them reference the same local variable?

```
void Test(IList list)
{
    int i = 0;

    list.Any( a => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda one says: {0}", i++); return true;} )
        .Any( a => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda two says: {0}", i++); return true;} );

}
```

I'm pretty sure I know the behavior here.  My question is, where exactly is `i` stored?

Comment: FWIW, that code doesn't compile. `Any()` is an extension method off of `IEnumerable<T>` and is expecting a `Func<T, bool>` not `Action`.

Comment: @Cameron Unless they have their own `Console` class with their own `WriteLine` method that returns a boolean.  (And also their own `Any` extension method for `IList`, since the LINQ `Any` method doesn't take an `IList`).

Comment: All local variables are stored on the execution stack.

Comment: @jdweng That's simply wrong, as is the case for the code shown here, and it even contains the quote form the language docs explaining where the local is stored (and how it couldn't be on the stack).  Closures couldn't possibly work if the variable needed to be stored on the stack, as the variable needs to exist after the method has completed, which can't happen if it's stored on the stack.

Comment: First, memory has to be some place and local variables are placed on stack.  Second i is not part of the lambda expression so the quote from the language doc doesn't apply.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, memory has to be in some place, but local variables are not necessarily placed on the stack. Sometimes they're stored in registers, sometimes they're hoisted to be fields of a compiler generated class, like here, or in cases of iterator blocks or `async` methods, and yes, *sometimes* they're on the stack.  As to this case, yes `i` is used in the lambda expression (and declared outside of it), so the quote from the language docs does apply.

Comment: You are not correct.  A lambda is  compiled method like every compiled method has a parameter list.  'i' is passed to the compiled code in the parameter list and is still a local variable.  When a local variable is a class object it is a local variable pointer to the class space and the pointer is on the stack.  Yes in some cases the compiler will store local variables in a register, but that is rare and only occurs over a few lines of source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one closure class for that method, rather than one per anonymous method.  That *one* class will have two instance methods and a field.  The field will store the value of `i`, and the two methods will each correspond to your two anonymous methods.